# Google Maps Markers aren't showing on map with IE

Tags: xml, image, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am really at a standstill because of IE. So I have a website with a map and I'm downloading the data from an XML file using geocodezip's js extension to place the markers and respective infowindows. Everything works fine when I open the site with Firefox, Chrome and Safari but the markers won't display on IE. However, I am also using a separate marker for geolocating the user's position and that also works on IE so I am not sure if the issue is with the image, my defining the marker or if it's the xml download part. For some reason, the reveal modal of my banner divs doesn't work on IE too but that's another issue I'm looking into. The website is still WIP but I'm leaving it on for a couple of days: [Website](http://www.dogeglobal.com)

This is where I define the icon image and then the marker itself:

```
    var image = {
        url: 'Images/shibatiny.png',
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(90,44),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(45,22)    
        //backgroundPosition: "-50 0"
    };
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            icon: image,
            shape: shape,
            map: map,
            title: name,
            zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
```

This is the part where I download data from xml and define the infowindow content 'html' (sorry for the messy code, need to clean it):

```
        downloadUrl("XML/database.xml", function(doc) {
            var xml = xmlParse(doc);
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
                var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
                var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                var category1 = markers[i].getAttribute("category1");
                var category2 = markers[i].getAttribute("category2");
                var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                var city = markers[i].getAttribute("city");
                var postcode = markers[i].getAttribute("postcode"); 
                var state = markers[i].getAttribute("state");   
                var country = markers[i].getAttribute("country");
                var phone = markers[i].getAttribute("phone");   
                var email = markers[i].getAttribute("email");
                var website = markers[i].getAttribute("website");
                var description = markers[i].getAttribute("description");
                var facebook = markers[i].getAttribute("facebook");     
                var twitter = markers[i].getAttribute("twitter");                                                                                                   
                var html = '<div id="infoWindow">';
                html += '<b style="font-size:16px; line-height:100%">'+name+'<\/b>';
                html += '<br/><img width="350px" height="6px" src="Images/line1.png"><br/><p style="color:#676868; line-height:2px !important">'+address+'<\/p>';
                html += '<p style="color:#676868; line-height:2px !important">'+city+', '+postcode+'<\/p>';
                html += '<p style="color:#676868; line-height:2px !important">';                    
                if (state) {var html = html + state+', '};                  
                html += ''+country+'<\/p>';
                if (phone) {var html = html + '<p style="padding-top:5px !important; line-height:2px !important"><b>Phone: <\/b>'+phone+'<\/p>'};
                if (website) {var html = html + '<p style="line-height:2px !important"><b>Web: <\/b>'+website+'<\/p>'};
                if (email) {var html = html + '<p style="line-height:2px !important"><b>Email: <\/b>'+email+'<\/p>'};                   
                //if (phone) {var html = html + '<b>Phone: <\/b>'+phone+'<br/>'};       
                //if (website) {var html = html + '<b>Web: <\/b>'+website+'<br/>'};     
                //if (email) {var html = html + '<b>Email: <\/b>'+email+'<br/>'};               
                if (description) {var html = html + '<p>"' +description+ '"<\/p>'};
                if (website) {var html = html + '<div class="infoweb"><a target="_blank" href="'+website+'">Website</a></div>'};
                if (email) {var html = html + '<div class="infoweb"><a href="mailto:'+email+'">Email</a></div>'};
                if (phone) {var html = html + '<div class="infoweb"><a href="tel:'+phone+'">Call</a></div>'};                   
                html += '<br/>';
                //html += '<a target="_blank" href="'+website+'">Website<br/><br/><\/a>';               
                //html += '<\/div>';
                html += '<div class="infoweb2">';
                if (email) {var html = html + '<a href="mailto:'+email+'" style="text-decoration:none"><img class="infobottom" width="30px" src="Images/emailsmall.png"> <\/a>'};
                if (facebook) {var html = html + '<a target="_blank" href="'+facebook+'" style="text-decoration:none"><img class="infobottom" width="30px" src="Images/facebooksmall.png"> <\/a>'};                 
                if (twitter) {var html = html + '<a target="_blank" href="'+twitter+'" style="text-decoration:none"><img class="infobottom" width="30px" src="Images/twittersmall.png"><\/a>'}; 
                var html = html + '<\/div>';            
                var html = html + '<\/div>'; //(if use this, remove html += '<\/div>'; )
                var marker = createMarker(point,name,html,category1,category2,address,country,city);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a javascript error:

```
Webpage error details

Message: 'documentElement' is null or not an object
Line: 571
Char: 8
Code: 0
URI: http://www.dogeglobal.com/
```

IE doesn't think [your XML](http://www.dogeglobal.com/XML/database.xml) is valid.

```
The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

An invalid character was found in text content. Error processing resource 'http://www.dogeglobal.com/XML/database.xml'. Li...

<marker lat="49.222402" lng="17.654174" name="CEU Servers" category1="web" category2="Computer Service" address="J.A. Bat...
```

It has character encoding problems. [w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dogeglobal.com%2FXML%2Fdatabase.xml&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)